# How to format web api decimal result to two decimal spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

How to format web api decimal result to two decimal spaces?

I have a web api method that should return number '15321.39'. 
However the value returned is 15321.3900

My code sample is:

```
    [Route("GetDecimalValue")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(decimal))]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetDecimal()
    {
        try
        {
            decimal result = GetMyNumber(); // returns number such as 15321.39

            return Ok(result);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    } 

public decimal GetMyNumber(){
   return 15321.39m
}
```

Plese note I do not want to change the return type

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue, it correctly returns `"15321.39"`. What is the default culture/`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` of your server?

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you try using a custom format such as "{0:000.00}"?

Comment: @Kixoka it would change return type to string

Comment: @FedericoDipuma default and unchanged

Comment: In your sample you use `ToString`, but your question is how to return the decimal value in your format without turning it into a string?

Comment: Any time you use .ToString() the results are always going to be a string value!

Comment: @Kixoka good point, I have updated the question, and you are absolutely correct also I do not want that

Comment: @cpoDesign Have you tried Math.Round() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing the default formatter (in your case the JsonFormatter) for decimal type with your custom implementation. This is applied globally and for every decimal you will use as parameter of any `NegotiatedContentResult` (e.g. it will work out of the box for the `Ok` method in your sample).

First create a new MediaTypeFormatter:

```
public class MyDecimalFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public MyDecimalFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(decimal);
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
        TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        var decimalValue = (decimal)value;

        var formatted = decimalValue.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
        {
            writer.Write(formatted);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Then add it as first to formatters collection in your Web Api configuration:

```
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new MyDecimalFormatter());
```

You could add this line inside `WebApiConfig.cs` `Register` method, or in `Global.asax`/`Startup.cs`.

### Differences between this method and `result.ToString()`

**Using just `.ToString()` inside your action.**

Action:

```
//..
decimal result = GetMyNumber();
return Ok(result.ToString("F2")); //Ok receives a string as argument
```

HTTP Response body:

```
"15321.39" //This is a JSON string, not a number
```

---

**Using the custom `MediaTypeFormatter`**

Action:

```
//..
decimal result = GetMyNumber();
return Ok(result); //Ok recives a decimal as argument
```

HTTP Response body:

```
15321.39 //This is a JSON number
```

Comment: Your solution is great but in the end it returns the same thing as return return Ok(result.ToString("F2")) just added as filter

Comment: The difference is that `Ok(result.ToString("F2"))` returns a *string* (notice the double quotes in the response) while this way you return the *raw value* (a JSON formatted number, not a string). Which is what you asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to set an amount of decimal places directly:

```
        decimal result = 15321.39m;

        var stringResult = result.ToString("F2");
```

Or try to round it (if you don't want to return string):

```
        var roundedResult = Math.Round(result, 2);
```

Comment: the issue is that the number is begin displayed as #.#### instead of #.## when presenting the value using the api

Comment: @cpoDesign Is it a real issue? I think it should be handled by a consumer of API (or just use string).

Answer (score 2):

Now that you changed your code to returning a decimal, there is no difference between 15321.39 and 15321.3900.  That is, you don't format a DECIMAL to any number of places.  You format the output when you go to display it.  So you would have to change the code that uses that **decimal** return value and displays it with only two decimals.  It is not a problem in the API, it is a problem now in the code that uses the API to make sure that it uses the right number of decimals when it displays the returned value.