# Assign a decimal value always with one decimal place to a field of an object

Tags: c#

I have a legacy application where the DeductibleAmount is set to value 250.0. In my application I have to match to it exactly.I tried

```
decimal.Round(ruleDeductible.Amount, 1)
```

but it still shows `250` not `250.0`.

Is there any way to assign `ruleDeductible.Amount` the decimal value with a single decimal place.

The output of the method is passed to WebApi and the final output is json. When I compare legacy and the new system json, I see the difference in the number of decimal points.

[image: json compare]

Comment: Decimal types inherently store values up to a certain precision. You cannot restrict the precision to 1 digit. At runtime the precision can be achieved by by rounding and/or formatting when displaying. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0

Comment: _it shows 250 not 250.0_ - 250 is the same as 250.0 (when not in physics). How do you view that information? Try it with 250.5 and you should see 250.5. If you don't, your display might be wrong.

Comment: @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica In case of legacy and the project that I'm working, the output of the method is passed to a WebApi which results json in the end.

Comment: `"It's not about [...] formatting"` - you're sending JSON to a webapi. JSON is a string format, so it 100% _is_ about formatting!

Comment: Yeah I understand. I will edit my question. But then how will I end up getting one decimal point in the json

Comment: This might already have an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793132/how-to-format-web-api-decimal-result-to-two-decimal-spaces

Answer (score 0):

The point is that I was trying out to match the legacy and the new system output via the Api Responses which is the json in the end. So I have to deal with the formatting in json which is suggested by @Dan Rayson. [Handling decimal places of decimal numbers in WebApiResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793132/how-to-format-web-api-decimal-result-to-two-decimal-spaces)